# Runtime Error 91- Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm new to VBA and having an issue with the below code, each time any cell (other than one in Column G) is selected the following error appears;

"Runtime error 91 - Object varible or with block varible not set"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static mailSent As Boolean

    If Not mailSent And Range("G10:G250").Find("YES", MatchCase:=False).Count() > 0 Then
        SendMail
        mailSent = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SendMail()
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").createitem(0)
         .To = "helpdesk171@***.com"
            .Subject = "*** Facility Manager Update"
            .Body = "Hi Property Services, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Update made by Facility Manager which requires your attention." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Click Here <\\Internal_Gold Facility Inspection Action Tracker.xlsx>" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please amend the drop down in Column G accordingly (received/complete)" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & " Kind regards "
            .Send
     End With
End Sub
```

When I click debug it highlights the line - "If Not mailSent And Range("G10:G250").Find("YES", MatchCase:=False).Count() > 0 Then"

Any ideas what needs altering to prevent this error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Count` is a property, not a method. Remove parenthesis after it.

Comment: Thanks @Akina I tried your recommendation but still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your boolean but you need a test of Is Nothing in case Find doesn't get a match e.g.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static mailSent As Boolean
    Dim found As Range
    Set found = Range("G10:G250").Find("YES", MatchCase:=False)
    If found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not mailSent And found.Count > 0 Then
        SendMail
        mailSent = True
    End If
End Sub
```